# How to place selected text from any windows OS application. Analog ctrl+c

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, winapi, qt6.4.1

The program runs in the background, minimized to the tray. When you press the global hotkey, a function is called that should output selected text to the console (from any windows OS application).

I use QClipboard. I understand how to output to the console what is already in the buffer `clipboard->text();`, I understand how to write from my application to the clipboard `clipboard->setText();`
But I don't know how to write selected text from any windows OS application to the buffer
Thanks

Comment: The clipboard belongs to the user, not your application. Use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) and you won't have to trash the user's clipboard.

Comment: You probably want to implement a [clipboard format listener or a clipboard viewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard#monitoring-clipboard-contents)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I can do this via `clipboard->setText(); clipboard->text();` , as I wrote earlier, but this is within my application.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you for your response. Maybe you are right and I need to use IUIAutomation. Could you show a small example of usage? I've tried it and I'm having errors. added `LIBS += -lUIAutomationCore` in *.pro, `#include <Windows.h>
#include <UIAutomation.h>
#include <QString>

QString GetSelectedText()
{
    QString selectedText;
    IUIAutomation *automation = nullptr;
    .......
}`

 `Unknown type name 'IUIAutomation'`

Comment: A clipboard format listener gets notified whenever clipboard changes. If someone selects text in any Windows application and presses Ctrl+C, that text is copied to clipboard, at which point your listener would be notified and could retrieve the text from clipboard. Is this not what you want?

Comment: You appear to want to fake a paste operation from a user?  This is something that is very easy to abuse, so most OS's don't let just any application do it.  Is there a underlying problem you are trying to solve and this is the solution for that underlying problem?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I have an app. This application works in the tray. Let's say I found a word in the browser (in any Windows OS application) and I can highlight it. If a word is highlighted when pressing the ctrl+alt+O hotkey, my application launches a function that reads this highlighted word from another application and then outputs the meaning of this word as a pop-up window.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, Yes, as I said earlier, what you suggest I have already done via `clipboard->setText(); clipboard->text();`
That is, now my application can output to me what is already in the buffer and after pressing ctrl+C it outputs what has changed. But I want to avoid pressing ctrl+C

Comment: @Constantine I mean, any app that can do that can also read passwords someone highlights.  That kind of "looking over the user's shoulder" as they use other applications is restricted in modern OS's.

Comment: @Constantine I don't know?  Could be OCR for all I know; maybe it is just doing screenshots.  If you want to know what it does, there are applications that let you see what APIs a program uses, like "spy++", written by microsoft.